# CartoDB 2.0 Virtual Machine for AWS/RDS

Tags: carto, installation, linux, amazon-web-services, virtual-machine

I'm not a Linux person; I'm finding it very difficult to install CartoDB 2.0 on my virtual machine.

I believe there was a V1 AWS VM that was created at some point.

Are there any VMs that are available for experimentation using version 2.0 of CartoDB?

Comment: There are many linux distros which are you talking about. most linx is straight forward from command line. Installs can done with wget. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget the easiest will be ubuntu like https://gist.github.com/ohvitorino/9638870

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of information about CartoDB installation in this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cartodb). For example, this [topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cartodb/rUOqIdp6xwQ).

Comment: Would you mind posting the links as links with proper titles?